# Kentico invoice - Include link to product

Tags: e-commerce, transformation, kentico, invoice

I'm attempting to modify the stock Kentico e-commerce invoice to include a link to each product ordered.  I'm editing the Order_ContentTable transformation but am not seeing any obvious macro expression that represents the URL.  Can anyone suggest a macro that I could embed in an 
    `<a href="{% ??? %}">...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the following K# method:

```
{% GetProductUrl(SKUID) %}
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked perfectly.  I did surround it with GetAbsoluteUrl since it will be in an email message.
`{% GetAbsoluteUrl(GetProductUrl(SKUID)) %}`